# Trying to open Lightning app contained by VF by hitting Force.com site custom URL

Tags: force.com-sites

I'm trying to call Lightning application through a VF container by hitting Force.com site custom URL which includes "siteWelcomePage.vf" as Site Home Page. Like:

siteWelcomePage.VF :-

```
<div id="lightning" />

<script>
$Lightning.use("kamy:siteContainerApp", function() {
    $Lightning.createComponent("c:siteHomeScreen",
                               {},
                               "lightning",
                               function(cmp) {
                               });
});
</script>
```

siteContainerApp.app :

siteHomeScreen.cmp :

## Welcome Mr. Kamy

Independently VF and Lightning app is working fine....but by hitting Custom URL It's not working...wondering what I'm doing wrong here..

Answer (score 0):

LightningOut on Sites require you to use **salesforce communities** .Also your dependency app should include interface named "**ltng:allowGuestAccess**"

```
<aura:application access="GLOBAL" extends="ltng:outApp" 
implements="ltng:allowGuestAccess"> 

<aura:dependency resource="c:storeLocatorMain"/>
```